# What pause image version is to be used for which kubernate version

Tags: kubernetes

New to kubernetes. What I was understood is each kubernetes uses docker pause image to store namespace information.My question in which pause image goes well with which which kubernetes version? How to find that out? If I am using kubernetes 1.3.2 which pause image version should I use?

Comment: Any comments or user review will be usefull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kubelet has a default infra container image that it uses and it is hard-coded in each version. In normal circumstances, users should not need to manually set the image. In some cases, where people want to use their customized image, they can override this by passing a `--pod-infra-container-image` flag to kubelet.

http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet

Comment: My mistake.. can you plz vote up. So that people like me get correct answer